# Custom method for AlertDialog throws "Attempt to invoke ... on a null object reference" Android

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom `AlertDialog` which has an `ImageView`, 3 `TextView` and a Button to dismiss the dialog. I need to set the `ImageView` and the 3 `TextView`'s text from my `Activity`, So inside the custom `AlertDialog` class I've created the following method:

```
public class ProductDialog extends Dialog implements
android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button close;
    public ImageView pImage;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView utensils;
    public TextView preparation;

    public ProductDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_dialog);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.popClose);
        close.setOnClickListener(this);
        pImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.popImg);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popTitle);
        utensils = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popUtensili);
        preparation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popPreparazione);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.popClose:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    public void setImage(String urlImg) {
        Picasso.with(getContext())
          .load(urlImg)
          .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
          //.transform(new RoundedTransformation(10, 0))
          .fit().centerCrop()
          .into(pImage);
    }

    public void setTitle(String txtTitle) {
        title.setText(txtTitle);
    }
    public void setUtensils(String txtUtensils) {
        utensils.setText(txtUtensils);
    }
    public void setPreparation(String txtPreparation) {
        preparation.setText(txtPreparation);
    }
}
```

And I call them from my `Activity` like this:

```
pDetails = new ProductDialog(MyActivity.this);
        pDetails.setTitle("asd");
        pDetails.setUtensils("asd");
        pDetails.setPreparation("asd");
        pDetails.setImage(imageUrl);
        pDetails.show();
```

But as soon as `setTitle()` gets fired I get the following error:

> 07-23 13:03:10.810: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MyActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

What am I missing in order to make it work?

Comment: Your `title=null` at  `setTitle(...)`

Comment: Yeah but what does that mean?
Inside the OnCreate of the AlertDialog class I use title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popTitle);

Comment: Post your code properly first then i will give you solution

Comment: @MD i've posted the whole code for the AlertDialog class

Comment: Presumably, one of your `TextView` widgets is not found. We cannot really help you with that, as we do not have the full stack trace (to know which one is not found) and we do not have the layout (to compare your Java code with the layout widget IDs).

Comment: Refer this [http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/13/extend-dialog-class-write-its-button-click-activity-interfaces-android/](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/13/extend-dialog-class-write-its-button-click-activity-interfaces-android/)

Comment: You can read how to use Custom Alert Dialog here - androhub.com/android-alert-dialog/

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry I forgot to mention that the problem was not related to a specific TextView, the problem was related to the method that initializes the TextViews, I solved using the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling those setters when views are not initialized. onCreate() method is called when `show()` method is called. but these setters are being called before show method. that is causing that error.

If you want to set those values from mainActivity you have to make interface to get those values or send data in constructor.

I have modified you code that can explain you how to achieve that you want. there are plenty of ways, here is the simplest one:

```
public Activity c;
        public Dialog d;
        public Button close;
        public ImageView pImage;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView utensils;
        public TextView preparation;

        // variables those will handle values. i did not implement it for image you can do same for that also.
        private String titleValue;
        private String utensilsValue;
        private String preparationValue;

        public ProductDialog(Activity a) {
            super(a);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
            this.c = a;
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.product_dialog);
            close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.popClose);
            close.setOnClickListener(this);
            pImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.popImg);
            title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popTitle);
            utensils = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popUtensili);
            preparation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popPreparazione);
            title.setText(titleValue);
            utensils.setText(utensilsValue);
            preparation.setText(preparationValue);
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.popClose:
                dismiss();
                break; 
            default: 
                break; 
            } 
            dismiss();
        } 

        public void setImage(String urlImg) {
            Picasso.with(getContext())
              .load(urlImg)
              .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
              //.transform(new RoundedTransformation(10, 0)) 
              .fit().centerCrop() 
              .into(pImage);
        } 

    // Created  getter and setter to get get value form mainActivity. 
        public void setTitle(String txtTitle) {
            titleValue = (txtTitle);
        } 
        public void setUtensils(String txtUtensils) {
            utensilsValue = (txtUtensils);
        } 
        public void setPreparation(String txtPreparation) {
            preparationValue = (txtPreparation);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your dialog is not created. Use builder pattern to save the values before creating.